# Previous information still present within Object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a little confused. So I have a JavaScript game build in JS, HTML5 canvas, and Firebase. The weird thing I'm experiencing is when I play a game there isn't a problem as it sends the information to the backend. But if I refresh it's as if the previous score still is present so when information gets send, it gets sent twice. If I refresh again then it's 3X etc. In the image, you can see the name and score are present from previous rounds.

[Backend showing repetition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxMPq.png)

The block of code where the information gets sent is

```
  showInput() {
    document.getElementById("inputName").type = "text";
    document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        const scores = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
        let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        let score = this.score;
        let highScore = { name, score };
        scores.push(highScore);

        document.getElementById("inputName").type = "hidden";
        this.showLeaderBoard();
      }
    });
  }
```

But it is strange since when a new game gets created. The information in it, for example, the score says this.score = 0 and it shows that. Can someone explain why a previous score still persist?

Thanks for all your help and explanation.

** Remove Listener **

```
  showInput() {
    document.getElementById("inputName").type = "text";
    document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
      console.log("event added");
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        const scores = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
        let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        let score = this.score;
        let highScore = { name, score };
        scores.push(highScore);

        document.getElementById("inputName").type = "hidden";
        this.showLeaderBoard();
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("inputName").removeEventListener("keyup", e => {
      console.log("event removed");
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        const scores = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
        let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        let score = this.score;
        let highScore = { name, score };
        scores.push(highScore);

        document.getElementById("inputName").type = "hidden";
        this.showLeaderBoard();
      }
    });
  }
```

** Reset Function **

```
    const Game = require("./game");
const Background = require("./background");
var GameInstance = null;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let preGame = () => {
    const canvasStart = document.getElementById("start");
    if (canvasStart.getContext) {
      const ctxStart = canvasStart.getContext("2d");

      ctxStart.font = "30px games";
      ctxStart.fillStyle = "red";
      ctxStart.fillText(
        "Press R to Start!",
        canvasStart.width / 2 - 110,
        canvasStart.height / 2
      );
    }
  };

  document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && GameInstance) {
      const scores = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
      let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
      let score = GameInstance.score;
      let highScore = { name, score };
      scores.push(highScore);

      document.getElementById("inputName").type = "hidden";
      GameInstance.showLeaderBoard();
    }
  });

  preGame();
  document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
    if (
      e.key === "r" &&
      document.getElementById("inputName").type === "hidden"
    ) {
      let score = 0;
      const canvasStart = document.getElementById("start");
      if (canvasStart.getContext) {
        const ctxStart = canvasStart.getContext("2d");
        ctxStart.clearRect(0, 0, canvasStart.width, canvasStart.height);
      }
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const canvasEnemy = document.getElementById("enemy");
      const canvasScore = document.getElementById("scoreBoard");
      const canvasGameOver = document.getElementById("gameOver");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const ctxEnemy = canvasEnemy.getContext("2d");
        const ctxScore = canvasScore.getContext("2d");
        const ctxGameOver = canvasGameOver.getContext("2d");
        GameInstance = new Game(
          ctx,
          canvas,
          ctxEnemy,
          canvasEnemy,
          ctxScore,
          canvasScore,
          ctxGameOver,
          canvasGameOver,
          score
        ).start();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I suspect it is because you aren't removing the event listener from the input when you reset. That means that when the user enters the next score, the text box will send some score twice.

Comment: @lemieuxster Thank you for your input. I've tried to do what you recommended but not sure if I'm doing it right. I've edited the question and added removeEventListener. Was this what you meant? Thank you again for your help and explanation.

Comment: @StevenOssorio No. You should pass in the original function to `removeEventListener` not a new function that looks like it. Anyways why are you calling `showInput` on each reset? Just reset the game without calling `showInput` and it'll work even without removing the event listener.

Comment: ... can you post the reset code?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Of course. I added it to the bottom of the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `showInput` a method of `Game`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes. It's a function within the Game class. It is supposed to run when the players' ship health reaches 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code need to be slightely refactored as the way it is now is causing some very serious problems:

- Each instance of the game creates its own event listener for the input. That will send more and more requests with each new instance.
- The instances you think are destroyed are still alive. They are trapped in the closures created by the multiple event listeners. That is a major memory leak.

Remove the event listener from `showInput` function. Define it only once. It should just check the current game instance and sends its score to the server when an input happens:

```
var gameInstance = null;

document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && gameInstance) {                             // check if there is a game instance
    const scores = firebase.database().ref("scores/");
    let name = this.value;                                            // this is the input now
    let score = gameInstance.score;                                   // use gameInstance
    let highScore = { name, score };
    scores.push(highScore);

    this.type = "hidden";                                             // here too
    gameInstance.showLeaderBoard();                                   // ...
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
  // ...
  gameInstance = new Game(/* ... */);                                 // don't forget to store the gameInstance so the event listener will have access to it
  // ...
});
```

`showInput` should look like this:

```
showInput() {
  document.getElementById("inputName").type = "text";
}
```

Which just shows the input as it supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got a question. I've updated the section **restart**. It shows the changes made and the entire file as well. What I'm currently experiencing though is the GameInstance is returning undefined. Shouldn't it be defined once the game has been created?

Comment: @StevenOssorio Yes, it should be defined. Where does it says `undefined`?

Comment: When I do a console.log right under where I define GameInstance it produces an undefined. I'm also not able to send the input to the backend since the if clause never runs since GameInstance is coming out as undefined(false)

Comment: Right after `GameInstance`, it will be `null`. `GameInstance` won't get a value until `document.addEventListener("keypress"` fires up. Can you console log `GameInstance` inside `document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup"` and see what it logs when that event fires?

Comment: Strange when I put a console.log within document.getElementById("inputName").addEventListener("keyup"), I'm getting an undefined as it's output.

Comment: I found out why it was resulting in an undefined. I had it as new Game().start();. After refactorinf where gameInstance had the .start() method, it is running perfectly and resolved the original issue. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Also thank you for helping me understand something I didn't know earlier in regards to memory leak and event listeners.

Comment: @StevenOssorio What an oversight! I can't believe I didn't spot that out, well done you! Also a little side note, since all of this is inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"`, you can move `var GameInstance = null;` to the top of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` so that it's hidden from the global scope. It should work without a problem.

Comment: ... also, you're welcome! I'm glad I could help! `;-)`